# Improving database performance SQL Server & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've created an application that has creeped into production, it has several tables like to one below.

I have a search query similar to below for each table. The database is growing by several thousand rows per day and I'm concerned about performance moving forward.

Can anyone suggest how I should re-engineer this process to increase efficiency?

I'm using Entity framework, C# and SQL Server.

Also is it possible to estimate system resource requirements for a database like this? Let's say for example if I had 600 000 rows?

Thanks in advance for the replies!

```
select top 100 * 
from table 
where given_name.contains(search) 
   or family_name.contains(search) 
   or session_number.contains(search)
```

Table structure:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[given_name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[family_name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[session_number] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[birth_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[start_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[reported_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[confirmed_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[dir_name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[info] [text] NULL,
[complete] [bit] NULL,
[approved_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[reported_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[sex] [bit] NULL,
[emergency] [bit] NULL,
[release] [bit] NULL,
[stop] [bit] NULL,
```

Comment: 600,000 rows is not that many.

Comment: It'd be useful if you would post execution plans and indexes. But first thing I could advice, would be using `CONTAINSTABLE` and multiple `UNION ALL` statements instead of `OR`s.

Comment: side note: using `top` without using `order by` is bad practice. No relational database guarantee the order of records that returns from a select statement without an `order by` clause.

Comment: i find funny the use of a bit for gender information :-) but i think it's related with the name of the field

Comment: @Paolo haha to be completely honest I changed the names of all the fields before posting. In the database it's gender. (I'll let that bit slide)

Answer (score 0):

600.000 rows is not so much rows so actually you can go on with your approach.

If it will increase there is 1 problem and one potential problem:

- The query has Contains clause that EF translates into SQL like similar to this pattern Like '%%'. The optimizer will not use the index on given_name, family_name and session number. You can evaluate SQL Server full text search that is not directly supported by Ef but there are some libraries (few lines of code) to enable a support. You can find one of them here
  http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch
- The second problem is related to OR optimization if there are the right indexes (is not your case!!!). The DBMS in this case can work in 2 ways:

  1. Table scan evaluating the WHERE CLAUSE;
  2. Retrieve 3 different temporary tables (1 for every OR condition) than make a UNION (not a UNION ALL that is less expensive but the result is different). A UNION is a merge of tables so the DBMS could sort temporary tables if there are several records or just work on the 3 temporary tables with table scans (sort on REC_ID not on the index used to solve the OR clause)

So quite expensive approach in both cases but if you need really an OR clause is the best approach. Also, the DBMS works on index statistics so it will probably make a better choice than a programmer choice (we hope so).

If you don't mind to have duplicated records you can split the query in 3 different queries and make a sql UNION (Concat in LINQ). Take care becouse a single record that is ok for more than one OR condition will appear more times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a stored procedure to handle your search. Also, to avoid OR you could use [Full-Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Then use in the stored procedure using Full-Text Search like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_SearchTable
    @searchTerm VARCHAR(100) 
    -- searchTerm should be like *john*
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   theTable
    WHERE  CONTAINS((given_name,family_name,family_name), @search)
END
```

Make sure you add the wild cards for Full-Text Search * term * (without spaces).

You can add the stored procedure to EF like described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896231(v=vs.100).aspx)